# jfet series switch isn't pulling the output to 0V

Tags: jfet

I gave a square wave [-10, 0] across gate-source and the input is dc 10V.
When the square wave is -10V, I thought the jfet cutsoff and the output would be 0V. But I'm getting ~3.1V at the output. Why is this so? Am I applying the gate control square wave correctly?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRhGtw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, this is a chopper circuit given in my textbook. I'm expecting the output to be a square wave of 10V peak to peak starting at 0V..

Comment: Try making R2 smaller like 10 kohm

Comment: I was reading it wrong. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @Andyaka I made R2 = 1 kohm and the ouput reduced to 2.5V from the earlier 3.1V. Is 1 kohm also large?

Comment: Try reversing the gate drive voltage source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the symbol matches the one from the datasheet, you are applying a voltage to gate-drain, and not gate-source. Attach the AC source to the gate and source  (right side of the FET). Here is the output characteristic of this FET.

[image]

I took the liberty of simulating your circuit. Apparently your AC supply was not properly set.

[image]

Comment: Aren't JFETs symmetric?

Comment: Ah good eye but even after flipping the jfet, the output remains unchanged... looks it is symmetric and drain is not special :(

Comment: vtolentino actually that worked! Insead of flipping the jfet, I connected the gate square wave across gate and output and the output is going to 0 new XD

Comment: I am glad it worked. :)